# C++ Constructor Inheritance of Circle

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am having trouble with my circle constructor which is inherited from the `Point2D` class.

**shape.h**:

```
 #pragma once
 class Shape {
    public:
      virtual float area() const = 0;

      virtual float circumference() const = 0;
  };
```

**Point2D.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "Shape.h"

template<class T>
class Point2D : public Shape {
  protected:
      T x, y;
  public:

    Point2D() : x(0), y(0) { }

    Point2D(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) { }

    T getX() const;

    T getY() const;

    void setX(T x);

    void setY(T y);


};

template<class T>
T Point2D<T>::getX() const {
    return x;
}

template<class T>
T Point2D<T>::getY() const {
    return y;
}

template<class T>
void Point2D<T>::setX(T x) {
    Point2D<T>::x = x;
}

template<class T>
void Point2D<T>::setY(T y) {
    Point2D<T>::y = y;
}
```

**Circle.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "Point2D.h"
#include "CustomException.h"

template<class T>
class Circle: public Point2D<T> {
  protected:
    T x, y, radius;
  public:

    Circle() : x(0), y(0), radius(0){}

    Circle(T x, T y, T radius) : Point2D<T>(x,y), radius(radius) { }

    T getRadius() const;

    void setRadius(T radius);

    virtual float area();

    virtual float circumference();


};

template<class T>
T Circle<T>::getRadius() const {
  return radius;
}

template<class T>
void Circle<T>::setRadius(T radius) {
  Circle<T>::radius = radius;
}

template<class T>
float Circle<T>::area() {
  return 3.14*radius*radius;
}

template<class T>
float Circle<T>::circumference() {
  return 3.14*2*radius;
}
```

I get these errors:

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘Circle<int>’
Circle<int> *circleInt = new Circle<int>(2, 2, 4);

because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Circle<int>’:
class Circle: public Point2D<T> {
  virtual float Shape::area() const
  virtual float area() const = 0;
  virtual float Shape::circumference() const
  virtual float circumference() const = 0;
```

Why am I getting these errors? How can I fix this?

Comment: You are not actually overriding the virtual methods of the `Point2D` class, you are instead creating new ones that don't have the `const` qualifier. (C++11 added the `override` keyword that would allow you to spot that mistake easier)

Answer (score 0):

Just got it!  Since I need to override the virtual method area() and circumference() from shape.h, the method of area() and circumference() need to change.  And they always need to change to constant method.

```
 virtual float area(); >>>>>> float area() const override;
 virtual float circumference; >>>>>> float area() const override;
```

Comment: Just remember the following rules: 1)whenever you have virtual function in your class that is not implemented you have an abstract class, 2)`new` cannot be used with an abstract class and 3)whenever you inherit from such an abstract class you also inherit the not implemented virtual functions. If you don't override these and provide an implementation your derived class also becomes abstract.